# How to change dropdown submenu second level background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

How to change dropdown submenu second level background?​

I was trying to use header#top .sf-menu .sf-menu li ul li a {background-color: #058486 !important;}​ but it's not worked.

The CSS always overwrited by the theme options javascript.

You can check the site at http://s.id/9U0 You can hover the Products menu then you will see 2 submenu level. I just want to change the 2nd level submenu background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an internal CSS code on that page that forces the background color. You can override this only by using inline CSS code or insert another internal CSS code after the block from the theme.
You could edit the footer.php file and insert below code:

```
<style>header#top .sf-menu li ul li a {
    background-color: #058486 !important;
}</style>
```